# Retaining fragment state after receiving activity result

Tags: android-fragments

I have an Activity A that consists of Fragment A. Inside Fragment A, I start Activity B with startActivityForResult(). When I receive the result from Activity B, all views values in Fragment A that had already been set before return to their default values. How to retain the all views values in Fragment A?

Below is the implementation:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xlistview);
    xItemArrayList = new ArrayList<XItem>();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.menu_item_add:
            initialiseList();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void initialiseList(){
    xListAdapter = new xListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_list, xItemArrayList);
    xListAdapter.setxListListener(new xListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickStart(View view) {
            openAutocompleteActivity(Constant.VIEW_START);
        }

    });
    xListView.setAdapter(xListAdapter);
}

private void openAutocompleteActivity(int selectedView) {
    this.selectedView = selectedView;
    try {
        // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
        // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt the user to correct the issue.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(getActivity(), e.getConnectionStatusCode(), 0 ).show();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily resolvable.
        String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " + GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);
        Log.e(Constant.TAG_ERROR, message);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
    if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
        if (resultCode == Constant.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getActivity(), data); 
            if (selectedView == Constant.VIEW_START){
                start = place;
                ((TextView)xListView.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textview_start)).setText(start.getName());
            }else if (selectedView == Constant.VIEW_LAST){
                last = place;
                ((TextView)xListView.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textview_last)).setText(last.getName());
            }

        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getActivity(), data);
            Log.e(Constant.TAG_ERROR, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());
        } else if (resultCode == Constant.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
            // the user pressed the back button.
        }
    }
}
```

There are two views in R.layout.item_list, R.id.textview_start and R.id.textview_last. On select each of the view, Activity B will start and on finish Activity B, the result will be displayed on the view itself. However, every time Activity B starts and finishes, previous values of the two views disappear and return to default. I have tried SavedInstanceState, but it does not work. It seems when Activity B returns to Activity A (with Fragment A in it), system goes to OnResume() of Fragment A without going to onCreatedView() of Fragment A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 method:
1st: use sharedpreferences to store the data. Now this data is accessible next time also the app is used. So after displaying the old data, just reset the data in sharepreferences to blank.

2nd: use bundle to transfer data to the activity and then just retrieve the same back.

Use a bundle to transfer data from one activity to another activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY_NAME", "Abrakadabra");
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivityName.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i)  <-- new activity started
```

Then in the receiving activity: Put this code in the onCreate method

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringdata = bundle.getString("KEY_NAME");
```

To pass data from activity to fragment: Put this code anywhere

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY_NAME", "Abrakadabra");
MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
myfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in the onCreateView method of the fragment add this code

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String stringdata = args.getString("KEY_NAME");
```

Comment: Thanks suku for the answer. Method 1 is doable if the values I am trying to keep are of primitive types. Method 2 is doable if from transition from Activity B to Fragment A is coded manually, where system will go to onCreateView() of Fragment A. However, since I am starting Activity B with startActivitywithResult(), transitioning from Activity B to Fragment A will not make the system go to onCreateView() of Fragment A, it will go to onActivityResult(). I decided to reset every views value in onActivityResult(), as written in my ans.

Answer (score 0):

Since Fragment A is waiting for Activity B's result, Activity A (where Fragment A is) will go to pause state. When Activity B returns results, Fragment A will resumes without going through onActivityCreated(). Thus, saving instance state will not work. Currently, the only solution I can think of is as below.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

// Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
    if (resultCode == Constant.RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
        Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getActivity(), data); 
        if (selectedView == Constant.VIEW_START){
            start = place;
        }else if (selectedView == Constant.VIEW_LAST){
            last = place;
        }

    } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getActivity(), data);
        Log.e(Constant.TAG_ERROR, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());
    } else if (resultCode == Constant.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
        // the user pressed the back button.
    }
}

if(start!=null)((TextView)xListView.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textview_start)).setText(start.getName());    
if(last!=null)((TextView)xListView.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textview_last)).setText(last.getName());
```

}

All the views values are re-set in onActivityResult(). When Activity A/Fragment A goes into pause state, it retains global variables values. Thus, for this implementation to work, start and last must be declared as global variables in Fragment A. Please suggest a better solution, if any.